# Java NoSuchMethodError minecraft.getMinecraft()

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am coding a minecraft mod for 1.8.9 and everything else works except for this one line. The file basically looks like

```
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class EventHandler {
    private FontRenderer renderer = Minecraft.getMinecraft().fontRendererObj;
    //other funcitons
}
```

The crash logs tell me

```
net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getMinecraft()
```

This is the only line I am using Minecraft.getMinecraft(). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

does the method exist when you decompile it, maybe you relocated something without knowing it

Comment: Yes, it exists in my decompiled .class file